# How can I tokenize $PATH by using awk?

Tags: bash, awk

How can I tokenize $PATH by using awk?

I tried 3 hours, but it totally screwed out.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1

while true; do
  token=$($echo $PATH | awk -F ':' '{print $"$i"}')

  if [ -z "$token" ]; then
    break
  fi  

  ((i++))

  if [ -a "$TOKEN/$1" ]; then
    echo "$TOKEN/$1"
    break
  fi  

  break
done
```

When I run this code, I got

```
/home/$USERID/bin/ff: line 6: /home/$USERID/bin:/usr/local/symlinks:/usr/local/scripts:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/$USERID/bin: No such file or directory
```

How can I change my program?

Comment: Did you set `$echo` to something? Or did you mean `echo` without `$`?

Comment: The error message is caused by the dollar sign, in fact. Since `$echo` is an empty variable, it's trying to execute the `PATH` as a command.

Answer (score 7):

What are you trying to do?

This will let you iterate against the individual paths:

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

As @SiegeX notes, an even shorter version works

```
echo $PATH | while read -d ':' line; do echo $line; done
```

Comment: Sure enough... adding that version.

Comment: @lymose: I believe I have what you are looking for. Please take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Do the whole thing in awk

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v addPath="$1" 'BEGIN{RS=":";ORS=addPath "\n"}{$1=$1}1' <<< $PATH
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ addPath="/foo"
$ awk -v addPath="$addPath" 'BEGIN{RS=":";ORS=addPath "\n"}{$1=$1}1' <<< $PATH
/usr/local/bin/foo
/usr/bin/foo
/bin/foo
/usr/games/foo
/usr/lib/java/bin/foo
/usr/lib/qt/bin/foo
/usr/share/texmf/bin/foo
./foo
/sbin/foo
/usr/sbin/foo
/usr/local/sbin/foo
```

Comment: @lymose No problem. Please select the answer that best solved your question by clicking the 'checkmark' next to the vote count.  Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1):

I think simple `tr : \\n` would suffice. Pipe it with `sed 's#$#blabla#g'` to add something to the lines and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use external tools such as awk or tr to tokenize the PATH. Bash is capable of doing so:

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=:
for p in $PATH
do
    if [ -a "$p/$1" ]; then
        echo "$p/$1"
        break
    fi
done
```

The IFS is a bash built-in variable which bash use as an input field separator (IFS).

Comment: @lymose: I added the if... block to make it the way you want. I originally left it out since I thought it should be obvious.